# Detect swipe down and close View with animation Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have a search button that onClick opens an `UIView` that covers most of the screen (It's like an `UIAlertView`). The `UIView` has as first element an `UIImageView` 2 `UITextView` and a close `UIButton`, what I want to add now is a gesture recognizer that works like this:
When the user drags the `UIImageView` down it also drags the `UIView` and it close it.

I tried with the following code in order to detect the Swipe gesture:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeToDoMethod)];
[swipeGesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown];
[[self popupImage] addGestureRecognizer: swipeGesture];
```

But I don't know how to proceed after this, can someone point me to the right direction in order to reproduce the effect I want?

Comment: do u have scrollview ?

Comment: @Mr.T no I don't have a scrollView

Answer (score 0):

missing delegate:

```
....
[swipeGesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown];
swipeGesture.delegate=self;
....
```